# RSS Notification Android Application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, notifications, rss

Hello everyone I know this has probably has been asked a lot and I have tried to search but can't find the answers I'm looking for.

I'm trying to build a application for Android and iOS where the user can download the app and once its downloaded everytime there is a new article on the blog it will give the user a notification and when they click on the notification it will take them to the browser of their choice and to the blog article on the web.

I was just wondering what the best way to do this is without having to use a third party.

Basically in a nut shell, just a application that syncs up with the RSS evey so often and if there is a new article it would give them a notification that links to the new blog article on the web.

as for the actual visual of the app i was just going to put some information and maybe what time intervals to sync with the RSS.

If any of this didn't make since please tell me and ill try to explain it better.

Thanks everyone for the help in advance,

Zach

Answer (score -1):

I have made an app like this for Android, it's called "Toggelis Newsreader". You need to parse the incoming Rss feed with a sax parser for example, keep track of the news the user already read, keep a list of feeds the user wants to follow etc.
As for the update intervals, I let the user chose 15min, 30min, 1h etc or "auto". Auto adapts the frequency to the sites activity: frequent new infos --> interval down and vice versa.
You should not permit intervals < 15min as this could be perceived as aggressive by the scanned sites.

Comment: What would be a good way to add notifications in the status bar when there is a new article?

Answer (score -1):

```
private void notif(String message, int icon, boolean autoClosing) {
    final Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(icon).setContentTitle("Toggelis Newsreader").setContentText(message);
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidAnzeige.class);

    final TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(AndroidAnzeige.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    final long[] pattern = { 0, 500 };
    if (isVibrate())
        nBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
    if (isSound())
        nBuilder.setSound(sound);
    nBuilder.setAutoCancel(autoClosing);
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, nBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses! where should i type this code into? or does i matter?

Comment: The code I pasted is a method that should be called at the end of the parsing process, if you detect that there is some new item in the RSS-stream.